# Appending number values to an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, database, sum, append

I'm solving a problem to find all the multiples of 3 and 5 within a number that is inputted from the user.

I want to show all the multiples and their sum to the user.

I can't find a way to add the values to the array containing the multiples.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  

        
        // Input the number from user:
        System.out.println("Enter a number to calculate the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below it: ");
        int number = input.nextInt();
        
        int i = 1;
    
        int[] arr = {}; 
        
        
        System.out.println("The multiples of 3 and 5 below the number " + number + " are: ");
        
        while(i < number) {
            
            if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0 ) {
                System.out.print(i + ",");
                arr = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length + 1);
                arr[arr.length - 1] = i;
        }
            
            i++;
    }
        
        int sum = IntStream.of(arr).sum();
        
        System.out.println("The sum of these multiples is: " + sum);


        //Thank you :D
}
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a list instead of an array? You can grow a list

Comment: i run your code and it works well,what is your problem？

Answer (score 2):

Try just adding the multiples together as they are found.

You do not need an array to store them since your code is a) printing out the multiple found and then b) printing out the sum of the multiples

Answer (score 2):

instead of array you can direct sum of the multiple 3 and 5
int sum = 0
inside if statement

```
if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0 ) {
            System.out.print(i + ",");
             sum += i;
            //arr = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length + 1);
            //arr[arr.length - 1] = i;
}
```

and print out the sum